# Bind data to table using ng-repeat on ng-change of dropdownlist

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I want data to appear in table according to selected value. I want to bind data to table after data is fetched when ng-change of dropdownlist is triggered

```
   <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="prodctrl" >
    <select id="BrandDropdown" class="InstanceList" ng-change="GetBrandProd()" ng-model="Products">
    <option>Select Brand</option>
    @if (ViewBag.dataset != null)
    {
        foreach (string str in (string[])ViewBag.dataset)
        {
        <option value='@str.Split('/')[0]'>@str.Split('/')[1]</option>
        }
    }
</select>
    <table ng-model="Products">
        <tr ng-repeat="P in Products track by $index">
            <td >{{x.Id}}</td>
            <td >{{X.Rank}}</td>
            <td >{{x.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this the  code

```
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('prodctrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetBrandProd = function () {
        var Id = $('#BrandDropdown').val();
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url:  "/Home/GetProdBrand",
            params: {
                id:Id
            }


        })
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.Products = response.records;
        });

  }

})
```

I am able to get the data successfully in response.records. but after i get data nothing happens